# R – Divide columns using for loop and by referencing to the index number in their names

Tags: r, loops

I have 2 simple dataframes DF1 and DF2

```
ID <- c(1:10)
C1 <- rnorm(10,5,1)
C2 <- rnorm(10,6,1)
C3 <- rnorm(10,7,1)

DF1 <- data.frame(ID, C1, C2, C3)

ID <- c(1:10)
C1 <- rnorm(10,5,2)
C2 <- rnorm(10,6,2)
C3 <- rnorm(10,7,2)

DF2 <- data.frame(ID, C1, C2, C3)
```

Both have 4 columns with identical name (ID, C1, C2, C3) and 10 rows, but their values in C1, C2 ,C3 are different (random normal distribution with different std dev).

I have also created another dataframe called “DF_div” which simply divides DF2 by DF1.

```
ID <- c(1:10)
C1 <- DF1$C1/DF2$C1
C2 <- DF1$C2/DF2$C2
C3 <- DF1$C3/DF2$C3

DF_div <- data.frame(ID, C1, C2, C3)
```

However I would like to know how to do this with a loop by extracting and indexing the numbers from the column names (i.e. C1, C2, C3), so that eventually I get the same results. Because I have a file with more than 100 columns (C1 to C100) and I need to do the same calculation.

I attempted the code below:

```
for (i in 1:3){
  get(paste0("C",i)) <- DF1$get(paste0("C",i))/DF2$get(paste0("C",i))
}
```

And received an error: “attempt to apply non-function”

Thanks!

Comment: You don't need a loop. `DF1[-1]/DF2[-1]`

Comment: Thanks@Ronak Shah, your method indeed works, but I'm also curious to know why my for loop did not work.